# Resolution Setup for Precipitation Interpolation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted, precipitation

I am trying to interpolate rainfall data using the GDAL's Grid (Inverse Distance to a power) in QGIS 3.16.

Is there a way to specify the resolution of the result/change the size of pixel? The resulting raster file is always .05x.05 resolution and I want to make a .02x.02 resolution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to disagree with the first answer, but using the base `gdal_grid` utility you can most certainly set the output resolution. You need to specify the parameter `-tr` ("target resolution"). See the [gdal_grid man page](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html#interpolation-algorithms).

You would run something like:

```
gdal_grid -tr 0.02 -a invdist:power=2 -zfield January_di <input_data> <output_interp.tif>
```

Answer (score 0):

At least according to the documentation (https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis/gridinvdist.html) there is no way to control the output raster size. EDIT: As Micha stated out in his answer, this is possible if you run the GDAL algorithm from command prompt and use -tr flag. Sorry for mislead! :)

However, you can resample your .05 x .05 output file e.g. with GRASS's resampling algorithm (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass79/manuals/r.resamp.interp.html) to the resolution of your desire.